# School project, code is returning 'list is unhashable'

Tags: python

For all other times I've done things like this, it's worked. But now, suddenly, my Python is messing up.

Here's the code block that's returning errors.

```
enemyLS = ['Nazi Solder', 'Nazi Scout', 'Nazi Ranger', 'Nazi Commander', 'Armored Nazi']
# [HP, ranAtk, melAtk]
enemy = ''
enemyHP = ''
enemyRan = ''
enemyMel = ''
enemyMan = {
        'Nazi Soldier': [5, 3, 3],
        'Nazi Scout': [3, 2, 2],
        'Nazi Ranger': [5, 4, 2],
        'Nazi Commander': [6, 4, 4],
        'Armored Nazi': [7, 2, 3],
        }

def fight():
    fighting = True
    while fighting:
        enIn = rand.randint(0, len(enemyMan) - 1)
        enemy = enemyLS[enIn]
        enemyHP = enemyMan[enemyLS][1]
        enemyRan = enemyMan[enemyLS][2]
```

And the `enemyMan[enemyLS][1]` stuff has always worked. Always. I have absolutely no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: I think you meant to write `enemyHP = enemyMan[enemy][1]` and `enemyRan = enemyMan[enemy][2]`, otherwise you're passing the whole `enemyLS` list as the dictionary key. Also your while loop currently has no way of exiting.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `enemyMan[enemyLS[1]]`?

Comment: Alright yeah that worked feel free to downvote me to oblivion for this. Thank you.